# Adding plugin to PhoneGap app

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, phonegap-build

i have a phonegap project to convert in .apk by phonegap build: so i need to add a plugin from a directory inside my root project (specifically, the plugin is cordova-plugin-fcm-config from https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-fcm-config and i follow all the instruction), but when i build my app i have this error:

> Failed to fetch plugin
>   cordova-plugin-fcm-config@cordova-plugin-fcm-config via registry.
>   Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is
>   incorrect. Check your connection and plugin name/version/URL. Error:
>   No compatible version found:
>   cordova-plugin-fcm-config@'cordova-plugin-fcm-config' Valid install
>   targets: ["1.0.0"]

How can i resolve this?

Thanks ;)

Comment: Please share your config.xml

Comment: Thanks for reply: after multiple tries, i've changed the plugin to implement the push notification functionalilty, adding  '<preference name="android-build-tool" value="gradle"/>
   <plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" source="npm"  spec="~1.8.4" >
    <param name="SENDER_ID" value="XXXXX" />
   </plugin>' to my Config.xml, but i'm getting issues on PushNotifications not defined :(

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line to your config.xml

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-fcm-config">
```

cheers